# CSVMIDI converter, how to use?

Tags: csv, exe, midi

On the following website:
*http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/*
I found a tool that supposedly can convert CSV files to MIDI files and MIDI files to CSV files.

It contains two .exe files that should be able to do the trick.

However, these files only show a black terminal-like screen when opened. When I drag and drop files to them something seems to happen but no new files is generated.

The readme doesn't explain how to do this.

Can anybody help me with this?

I am busy making a random music generator. It's only using soundbeep right now, but I want multiple tracks, hence my need to be able to create midi files from CSV files. If anybody's interested in the music generator I'd gladly share the code (though it's still a bit basic)

Comment: [documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is only available on a Windows system, If you are on Windows, open the `Midicsv.exe` for example, then you should turn another cmd on; In your newly opened cmd, change to where your files in(or you can input exact path later), then in your cmd:

```
midicsv [-u -v] [Your MIDI file] [Your out put path with csv name]
```

then you can find your generated csv file.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I tried using your suggestion, but I would receive the following error: ``midicsv: Unable to to open MIDI input file [-u``

Comment: [ text here ] means fill in the blank or choose an option. So an example would be `midicsv.exe test.mid test.csv`